# How do I write an article about the negative effects of a topic and my experiences with that topic?

Tags: non-fiction, research

Ok let's pretend I'm writing about abuse (or bullying or another topic( and my experience with it (I don't want to state the real topic here). I want to write a psychological and scientific article/paper/post that is about my experience with abuse and the negative effects of it (like the emotional damage of domestic abuse that women feel for example). I am not a scientist, but I want to write an article for it. I know how to do research, but I don't know how to structure my article?

Comment: Are you trying to write an article about the topic (drawing illustrations from your experience), or a more-personal article about your experience?  Who is the audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you structure your article will largely depend on who your readers are and what you would like them to learn from it.

If your readers are people from the scientific community, then you would structure your article based on what new findings, discoveries or trends that your research has led you to. A title for this kind of article would be, "Bullying at School is Linked to Bullying at Home." This was actually taken from a list of articles at Science Daily:

http://www.sciencedaily.com/articles/b/bullying.htm

If your readers are people who experienced the topic, then you would structure your article based on what actions you would like your readers to take after reading. A sample title could be, "10 ways you can help your child deal with bullying" or "Is your child a bully? Here's what you can do." The research you conduct would then be interwoven as supporting points that give your main idea more credibility.